Need help with Dummy Output Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
My problem is that I recently bought a laptop and it is not a super computer so the performance was bad with Windows 11 (Default OS) then I decided to change to Ubuntu 22.04 (I already have it in my Desktop PC with no problems). Once intalled Ubuntu I realize that there is no sound, I saw the config and the output says "Dummy output" and there is not any other option to select.
So i tried with a lot of things and I have some info that maybe unorganized as I have it will not work for me but maybe some one can help me. Thanks.
Info:
lspci | grep -i audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium SIlver Processor High Definition Audio (Rev 06)

In Windows I had the same problem of no sound (Before Install Ubuntu I thought that would have been a good idea to try with reinstall windows) the solution was just install oficial drivers from the page but are only for windows, then in the next link you can see what the laptop is and the drivers that solved the problem for windows. (Maybe you should to translate the page)
https://soporte.exo.com.ar/support/solutions/articles/22000281155-notebook-exo-smart-serie-lt2
The graphics are: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)

I encountered similar sound problem too, There's SoundTroubleshooting for more information. First to identify which driver is working.
lspci -v | grep -A6 -i audio
...
...
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

then use dmesg command to see if this driver works fine
sudo dmesg | grep -i audio

Sometimes the so-called inbox driver doesn't work normally,
you might want to use alternative way to solve the problem.
please refer to another question or this one

I solved changing to the last ubuntu version.

I finally fixed it installing ubuntu 24.04
